# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart does not contain a definition for Chartareas

Tags: c#

//Created a chart in excel using C#. When trying to format the chart using the method "ChartAreas", I keep getting error messages (setting the axis interval, adding a stripline). Been searching the web for the last two hours but can't find the reference i am missing (if that's the issue). Tried to find an alternative method to use for formatting which would work, but everyone seems to use "Chartareas".
Below my code, hoping someone can help, thx

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer;
    using System.IO;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization;
    using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization;
    using System.Web.UI.Design;

     //part of code where am having difficulty - see ChartAreas methods below
public void createChart()
        {
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                //add data 
                for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }

                }
                MessageBox.Show("data loaded to excel");

                 Excel.Range chartRange ;                

            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(420, 15, 700, 400);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
            int rangebottom = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("G1", "H"+rangebottom);
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
            chartRange.Columns.AutoFit();            

            //Gets the Axes
            Axis Xaxis = chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Axis;
            Axis Yaxis = chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Axis;       
            //Sets X-axis attributes
            Xaxis.TickLabels.Font.Size = 8;
            Xaxis.HasTitle = true;
            Xaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "WW-Year";
            //Sets Y-Primary Axis attributes
            Yaxis.TickLabels.Font.Size = 8;
            Yaxis.HasTitle = true;
            Yaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Demand";

            chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(new StripLine());
            //chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 252, 180, 65);
            //chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].StripWidth = 40;
            //chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].Interval = 10000;
           // chartPage.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].IntervalOffset = 20;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what *error messages* you are getting?

Comment: Error messages:
"'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart' does not contain a definition for 'ChartAreas' and no extension method 'ChartAreas' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
"The type or namespace name 'StripLine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"